# How to stop page to reload again after redirection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova, jquery-mobile-button

I'm developing an app using Phonegap, the problem is when I go to a page it changes the URL but doesn't load the page. It refreshes the page and put the user back on the same page where he was.

**Default URL:**
localhost/pg_proj/www/index.html#gameDashboardPage

User Clicks on a link to go to the below URL

localhost/pg_proj/www/index.html#pendingChallengesPage

In the address bar, it changes the URL from **#gameDashboardPage** to **#pendingChallengesPage** but it doesn't load the **#pendingChallengesPage** page, instead it just refreshes the page and put the user back on **#gameDashboardPage**

Any suggestions will be great thanks

Comment: You should provide a piece of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, it's not just refreshing the page. Your code on `#pendingChallengesPage` might contain code that redirects again back to it's previous. Please mention it, **Is the URL is persist after reload?** You've clearly stated that page content is not changing. What about the URL?

1) If you are redirecting inside a function twice, `return;` the function after it's first redirection.

2) Use `event.preventDefault();` if necessary.

Reply with some more details. if you could, throw few script here.

Comment: thanks for pointing in the correct direction, I mentioned window.location that's why it was doing like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `onclick` and try [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).